# What is exact redirect uri in instagram? How can i use that in ios app? "Enter a valid url" on instagram developer portal

Tags: ios, authentication, redirect, oauth, instagram-api

I'm using OAuth2Swift to using login with instagram, in my previous apps i did the same but now i am getting an issue.

My problem is related to the redirect_uri

Last time I used `"ig" + {client_id} + "://authorize"` but after some time, did the same thing for the another app then instagram devloper portal shows the "Enter a valid url".

Then I used `"https://ig" + {client_id} + "://authorize"` that time is worked for me.

But now I'm facing the same issue "Enter a valid url", while I tried all my possible solutions.

Can any one help me generate the valid redirect URI?

Answer (score 6):

instagram only support http and https, so you have to implement client-implicit oauth in a webview in iOS app and use the webview delagate method to read `access_token` from hash fragment of redirect-uri. Your redirect-uri can be `http://localhost/`

Comment: I have used: https://localhost:3000/callback as redirect uri and still getting Invalid redirect_uri exception @krisrak